# PHP mail() reaches GMail, Yahoo, but not other addresses

Tags: php, email

We have a confirmation script for our users, which uses the PHP mail() function. If I enter my own address (GMail or Yahoo) everything works perfectly. If however I enter the client's address, the function returns 1 but the email never reaches its destination. We checked spam but the email is not there either.

This is the PHP script I prepared:

```
$msg = "Body of the message";
$headers = "From: OUR TEAM <team@our_email.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$sendmail = mail('some@address.com', 'Trial email (testing...)', $msg, $headers);

echo ("Sent mail = ") . $sendmail;
```

The return value is always 1.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the SMTP response and see how the destination server replies. If the destination server replies with anything other than OK then this would lead you to the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I don't know how I can retrieve that response. Is it something I can do in the same PHP script? Or something totally different. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the mail() method is a boolean and returns either true or false so you can just install a network monitoring tool on the remote server in order to trace the TCP stream.

Comment: What OS are you running?